# echo json_encode($array) not returning what i expect it to return?

Tags: jquery, json

i have this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        refresh();
    });

    function refresh()
    {      
        $.post('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
        $("#subject").html(json.subject);
        $("#subject_id").html(json.subject_id);
        $("#unique_code1").html(json.unique_code1);
        $("#unique_code2").html(json.unique_code2);
        $("#unique_code3").html(json.unique_code3);
        });   
        window.setTimeout(refresh,30000);
    }   
</script>
```

then my html part:

```
foreach ($row as $r)
{
   echo "<tr>";
   echo '<td><a id = "subject_id" class="red_link" href="'.ADDRESS.'view_message.php?id='.$r['id'].'"><span id = "subject">'.$r['subject'].'</span></a></td>';
   echo '<td id = "unique_code1">'.$uniqueCode1.'<span id = "unique_code2" class="pink_text">'.$uniqueCode2.'</span><span id = "unique_code3">'.$uniqueCode3.'</span></td>';
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

my getMessageDetails.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include('header_application.php');

$limit = 15;
if(!isset($_GET['page']))
   $page = 1;
else
   $page = $_GET['page'];

$from = (($page * $limit) - $limit);
$row = $obj_clean->getMessages($_SESSION['user_id'], $from, $limit);

if (count($row) > 0)
{
    foreach ($row as $r)
    {
        $codeLength = strlen($r['unique_code']);
        $codeLength = strlen($r['unique_code']);
        $firstPartLength = $codeLength - 5;
        $uniqueCode3 = substr($r['unique_code'], -2);
        $uniqueCode2 = substr($r['unique_code'], -5, 3);
        $uniqueCode1 = substr($r['unique_code'], 0, $firstPartLength);

        $message_id = $r['id'];
        $subject = $obj_clean->getMessageDetails($message_id);
        $opened_once = $obj_clean->getOpenedOnce($message_id);
        if ($opened_once >= 1)
        {   
            $array['subject'] = "blablabla";
            $array['subject_id'] = $r['id'];
            $array['unique_code1'] = $uniqueCode1;
            $array['unique_code2'] = $uniqueCode2;
            $array['unique_code3'] = $uniqueCode3;
            echo json_encode($r);
            exit();
        }
    }    
}
?>
```

i did have the echo json_encode($r);
               exit();
outside the loop and dont think that that is the problem..the problem is with json/json_encode but dont know enough to figure it out...can some-one help please?

thank you

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Can you show an isolated example with less code?

Comment: nothing goes wrong..i inject a new message into the database table and wait for it to appear on my page..it does call getMessageDetails.php when i inspect element and click on the network tab(in chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

instead of result,

```
echo json_encode($r);
```

Comment: i did have it as echo json_encode($array); was just trying something..but to now avail :(

Comment: echo json_encode($array); i did and nothing is happening...what can it be please? how can i view what is in echo json_encode($array);

Comment: okey dokey...found the problem..in getMessageDetails.php is a foreach loop..it does return values BUT it returns the first new message not the LAST new one..and the first new one is already listed thus it si being re-listed...i need the foreach to return the last one??? any help please? thank you